# Determine if File Name Contain String in Listbox and Execute Next One

Tags: vb.net

This code below is Executing All files on the determined path. And I'm trying to filter it as you can see:

```
If isthere(bat, Form1.ListBox2) Then
      Run(sPath, bat)
End If
```

The problem is that after some specific (determined by the filter) file has been started , the next file won't be executed. How can I fix that.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
    Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sPath)
    Dim fileName As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*" + sExt)
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    If IO.Directory.Exists(sPath) Then
    Else
        MsgBox("Terjadi Kesalahan, Path tidak ditemukan atau tidak valid", vbExclamation)

    End If
    For Each file As IO.FileInfo In fileName
        list.Add(file.ToString())

    Next
    For Each bat As String In list
        If isthere(bat, Form1.ListBox2) Then
            Run(sPath, bat) 
        End If

        If bat.ToString = list.Last Then Exit For Else 
        If Form1.CheckBox1.Checked = vbTrue Then
            If MsgBox("Program Selesai dijalankan. Lanjutkan ke program berikutnya ?", vbYesNo + vbInformation) = vbYes Then  Else Exit For
        Else
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Where is the definition (code) for `isthere`?

Comment: Im sorry not place the code but that using InStr to find a string. My core Quest is why the next file won't be executed.

Comment: What is the code for the `Run` method/ function? Or is it in a library you are using in your project?

Comment: Just using For Each . and Not a library